# Getting Black Python code formatter to align comments

Tags: python, black-code-formatter

Yes, I'm, of the understanding that `black` gives very little leeway in getting it to act differently but I was wondering about the best way to handle something like this (my original code):

```py
@dataclass
class Thing1:
    property1: int                    # The first property.
    property2: typing.List[int]       # This is the second property
                                      # and the comment crosses multiple lines.
```

Now, when I run that through `black`, it gives me:

```py
@dataclass
class Thing1:
    property1: int  # The first property.
    property2: typing.List[int]  # This is the second property
    # and the comment crosses multiple lines.
```

which is not really laid out as I'd like.

Is there a way to get black to keep the comments lined up? I don't care which column it starts in per field, but it would be nice to return to the readable nature, with the comments within *each* field being lined up:

```py
@dataclass
class Thing1:
    property1: int  # The first property.
    property2: typing.List[int]  # This is the second property
                                 # and the comment crosses multiple lines.
```

If there's no way to do this, I'll probably either place multi-line comments before each field, or ensure all comments fit on the one line and add lengthier explanatory notes at the end of the dataclass definition:

```py
@dataclass
class Thing1:
    property1: int  # The first property.

    # This is the second property and the comment, while it can
    # have more characters, still crosses multiple lines.
    property2: typing.List[int]

@dataclass
class Thing2:
    property1: int  # The first property.
    property2: typing.List[int]  # This is the second property.

    # Note that the comments above now fit on the same line as the
    # field, and this comment here is meant to provide any needed
    # multi-line detail for ALL fields in this class.
```

That at least is still *somewhat* local to the data fields. But I'd rather find a way to have it line up comments similar to what I originally had, if possible.

Happy to entertain any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap your block with `# fmt: on/off`, so Black doesn't touch it.

```py
# fmt: off
@dataclass
class Thing1:
    property1: int               # The first property.
    property2: typing.List[int]  # This is the second property
                                 # and the comment crosses multiple lines.
# fmt: on
```

I usually prefer to relocate the comments and stick with default Black formatting.

Comment: I ended up basically doing one-line comments with more detailed notes preceding any of the fields (as you suggested). But this is good to know for any future issues where I don't like what `black` decides is best for me :-)